# HTML can't load image on page

Tags: python, html, css, django

in the following HTML, I want to load an image but as you can see below the image has been sent but not displayed. Any ideas? maybe a problem with CSS? (I am using materialized CSS)

[image: cmd]

```html
<html>

{% extends "main/header.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<img src="{% static 'images/MOA_LOGO_p.jpg' %}" alt="logo" >

{% endblock %}
```

EDIT: Inspector mode: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Add a width and height to the image see if that helps, you can check inspect elements for the rendered width and height of the image

Comment: @DeonDazy It didnt work :(

Comment: What does it say when you hover on the image in inspect elements?

Comment: @DeonDazy there is something but it's not displayed (check the question i added a screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Opacity is set to 0 in your CSS.

Set Opacity to 1 and you should see your image

```
.parallax-container .parallax img {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That should show the image, then change the CSS to your need but be sure to leave Opacity set to 1.

Comment: I fixed it by <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="logo" width=70px height=30px style="opacity:1;" >